# Difference between triumph and success

Tags: word-choice

Could you please shed some lights on the difference between *[triumph](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/triumph)*:

> verb
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>   1.0 Achieve a victory; be successful:
>   *they had no chance of triumphing over the Nationalists*
>
> 1.1 Rejoice or exult at a victory or success:
>   *she stopped triumphing over Mrs Ward’s failure*
>
> ODO

and *[success](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/success)*:

> noun
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>   1.0 The accomplishment of an aim or purpose:
>   *the president had some success in restoring confidence*
>
> 1.1 The attainment of fame, wealth, or social status:
>   *the success of his play*
>
> 1.2 [COUNT NOUN]
>   A person or thing that achieves desired aims or attains fame, wealth, etc.
>   *to judge from league tables, the school is a success*
>   *I must make a success of my business*

Comment: Welcome to ELU @Dang. The research I added to your question is the kind of research we expect from inquirers **before** they submit their questions. You should be able to answer your question quite well on your own now.

Comment: Thank you for your editing my question. My next ones will follow this standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Triumph**

> a great victory or achievement.

**Success**

> the accomplishment of an aim or purpose.

Both mean the same thing, but as you can see from the definitions, *triumph* has a more powerful connotation. *Success* is a more ordinary term.

It's common to state things like these:

Unfortunately Poland profited little or nothing by this great triumph, and now that she had broken the back of the enemy she was left to fight the common enemy in the Ukraine with whatever assistance she could obtain from the unwilling and unready Muscovites. (While talking about a victory in war or polictics, it's common to use 'triumph')

Explanation of our lack of success was unnecessary and we all retired for the night.('success' is a commonplace term)